# Vanilla JS: Capture wrapping element click, but never its children

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

I have a div (A) that contains another div (B).

When I click on A, I want `e.target` to be A. When I click on B, I also want `e.target` to be A.

Since you must have clicked on the wrapping element to get the inner element, how do you tell JS to never get B?

I know it has something to do with bubbling, but I've thrown everything I can at it and nothing seems to help.

```
// none of these work
e.preventDefault()
e.stopPropagation()
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
e.cancelBubble = true

// adding { capture: false } doesn't help either
```

Here's a JSBin reduced test case of the problem. https://jsbin.com/wezoyoyito/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget` instead, which always references the element that the listener is attached to (and not the inner clicked element):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.a').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.className)
  })
})
```

```css
.a {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.b {
  background: yellow;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  A
  <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to test the following code and should be able to work according to your needs.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.a').forEach(el => {

  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
     e.preventDefault();
     let target = e.target;
     while (target !== el) {
       target = target.parentNode;
    }
    console.log(Array.from(target.classList)[0])
  });

});
```